# Query GAE Datastore on Transformed Property Values

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on a Python NDB model on app engine that looks like:

```
class NDBPath(ndb.Model):
    path = ndb.StringProperty()
    directory = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: getDirectory(self.path))
    cat = ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=False)
```

Path is a file path, directory is the superdirectory of that file, and cat is some number. These entities are effectively read only after an initial load.

I query the datastore with various filepaths and want to pull out the `cat` property of an entity if either a) its path matches the queried path (same file), or b) if the entity's directory is in a superdirectory of the queried path. So I end up doing a query like:

```
NDBPath.query(NDBPath.directory.IN(generateSuperPaths(queriedPath)))
```

Where generateSuperPaths lists all the superdirectories in their full form of the queried Path (eg `a/b/c/d.html --> [/a, /a/b, /a/b/c]`)

Because these are read only, using a computed property is effectively a waste of a write as it will never change. Is there any way to query based on a dynamically transformed value, like

```
NDBPath.query(getDirectory(NDBPath.path).IN(generateSuperPaths(queriedPath)))
```

So I can save writing the directory as a property and just use it in the query?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, yes. They will end up doing the same and it will save you on write time and cost. Although it will make your query run slower (because of the added computation), so be wary of possible timeouts.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `yes`.  Computed properties were added exactly because "queries on transformed values" are otherwise **not** possible -- `getDirectory(NDBPath.path)` will fail here for example (as `getDirectory` is called with a non-`str`) and there's no way to "send a function over to the datastore" to be applied there to help your query!